# Mapping JSON object to Glass object not working - Ajax POST

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a custom form and wanted to create complex Sitecore items. I am using TDS auto-generated class with GlassMapper.

I am passing Glass object from controller to view, which then serialized to Json object. I am making necessary changes to Json object as per form field values and sending back to controller using POST method.

Everything seems to be working fine. But when i try to post an object which has non default values for GlassBase fields (In edit mode) like ID, Language etc. it's not working even though i have updated each property to public set. I do not wanted to create a ViewModel only for this purpose.

[image: GlassBase]

Note: This is working fine with fluent configuration.

Comment: > Note: This is working fine with fluent configuration.
Why not just use fluent config then? :)

Comment: We don't want to make that process manual when we add/remove any field from template. Auto generation takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into an issue with Automapping not working in Glass Mapper version 4.5.0.4 or 4.5.1.339-beta. So if you are using one of those versions it may be a Glass Mapper bug.

Comment: What do you mean by automapping? I am posting json object. Simple to complex type working fine. Issue with GlassBase properties only.